# Why does setting SO_TIMEOUT cause final read of SocketInputStream to return immediately?

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I'm working on a test harness that writes bytes over a socket to a server and reads the response.  I had a problem where the last read of the Socket's InputStream would pause for 20 seconds.  I fixed that, but don't understand why it worked.

The following method is given a java.net.SocketInputStream.  The call to *read(byte[], int, int)* was pausing for 20 seconds on the final read, the one that returns -1, indicating end-of-stream.

```
    private String getResponse(InputStream in) throws IOException {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesRead >= 0) {
        bytesRead = in.read(data, 0, 1024);    // PAUSED HERE ON LAST READ
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            bout.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        buffer.append(new String(data));
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

I was able to make the pause go away by setting SO_TIMEOUT on the socket.  It doesn't seem to matter what I set it to.  Even with socket.setSoTimeout(60000), the problem read in the method above returns immediately at end-of-stream.

What's happening here?  Why does setting SO_TIMEOUT, even to a high value, cause the final read on the SocketInputStream to return immediately?

Comment: SO_TIMEOUT doesn't have that effect. The real question here is why the pause? which can only be explained by the sender being slow to send the final data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds implausible.  Setting a socket timeout shouldn't have that effect.

I think the most likely explanation is that you *changed something else*, and *that* is what has fixed the pauses.  (If I was to guess, it would be that the server is now closing the socket where it wasn't doing that before.)

If this doesn't help, you will need to provide an SSCCE that other people can run to observe the effect.  And tell us what platform you are using.

Comment: Meant to respond to this months ago.  You are indeed correct.  The server changed to close the socket and that's why the final InputStream.read began to return immediately, as expected. Thanks.